# MongoDB query inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to use this mongoDB collection:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "627c4eb87e7c2b8ba510ac4c"
    },
    "Contact": [
      {
        "name": "ABC",
        "phone": 5501234,
        "mail": "abc@mail.com"
      },
      {
        "name": "DEF",
        "phone": 6001234,
        "mail": "def@mail.com"
      }
    ],
    "nomatter": "trash"
  }
]
```

search for `{"name":"ABC"}` and return only `{"mail":"abc@mail.com"}`.

It's possible to use find or it's necessary to use aggregate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Comment: Unfortunately not. All return a full json. I just wanted the fragment. But thanks for help!

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "Contact.name": "ABC" } },
  {
    $project: {
      Contact: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Contact",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.name", "ABC" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { "$replaceWith": { mail: { $first: "$Contact.mail" } } }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xuizXVSbhNd)

Comment: WoW, that's Amazing! I had never thought of using replaceWith to move up the hierarchy. So simple, but not found in other similar answers.